# How do I solve this $\lim\limits_{s\to \infty}\frac{2s^2}{s^2-4}$

Tags: limits, partial-fractions

How do I solve this  $$\lim_{s\to \infty}\frac{2s^2}{s^2-4}$$ .

I have tried partial fraction, but it does not give me a constant. And I know the answer is 2.

Comment: The answer is not $2$. Please check the expression.

Comment: If the degree of the numerator is less than the degree of the denominator, a rational function tends to $0$, if the argument tends to $\pm \infty$

Comment: The expression is $\frac{1}{s + 2} + \frac{1}{s - 2}$, how could it be > 1?

Comment: I am sorry. I have changed the expression. There was a typo.

Comment: Well you can try $f(s)-2=\frac{8}{s^2-4}\to 0$, it's basic but works you know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is $2$. Note that $\lim\limits_{s \to \infty} \frac{M}{s^p} = 0 $ for any $M$ finite and $p\geq 1$.
$$ \lim_{s \to \infty} \frac{2s^2}{s^2 - 4} = \lim_{s \to \infty} \frac{2}{1 - 4/s^2} = \frac{2}{\lim\limits_{s \to \infty } 1 - \frac{4}{s^2} } = \frac{2}{1} = 2 $$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :** $$\frac{2s^2}{s^2-4} = \frac{2}{1- \frac{4}{s^2}}$$

Comment: Thanks! Good hint!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative

$$\frac{2s^2}{s^2-4}=2+\frac{8}{s^2-4} \to 2+0=2$$

Answer (score 1):

$$L=\lim_{s\to \infty}\frac{2s^2}{s^2-4}$$
Using fraction decomposition:
$$=\lim_{s\to \infty}\frac{2s^2-8+8}{s^2-4}$$
$$=\lim_{s\to \infty}2+\lim_{s\to \infty}\frac{8}{s^2-4}$$
$$\implies L=2$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $s \to \infty$ we got a case for the rule of l'Hospital. Using this we get:

$$\frac{2}{2s}, s \to \infty $$
$$ \lim_{s\to \infty} \frac{1}{s}= 0$$

---

Edit:

Still l'Hospital's rule can be applied
$$\lim_{s\to \infty} \frac{2s^2}{s^2 -4}\stackrel{\text{l'hosp.}}{=}\frac{4s}{2s} =  \frac{4}{2}  = 2$$

Comment: Note the comments and the edit

Comment: Well...too late I guess :P Has been solved anyway